# Setting field values from a json in karate

Tags: karate

I have form fields names something like `data[name]`, `data[city]` and I have these field names written in a json file like below

```
"request" : {
"data[name]":"",
"data[city]":""
}
```

I was trying to set the value of these fields in feature file using karate code like below

```
set request.data[name] = 'testuser'
```

but when I print request json after assigning the value, json looks like below

```
"request" : {
"data[name]":"",
"data[city]":""
"data":{ 
"name" : "testuser"}
}
```

I want my json to look like below

```
"request" : {
"data[name]":"testuser",
"data[city]":""
}
```

Any idea, How would I be able to set above field value properly with karate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My goodness who designed this JSON >_<

You can use JS !

```
* def req = { 'data[name]': '', 'data[city]': '' }
* eval req['data[name]'] = 'foo'
* eval req['data[city]'] = 'bar'
* match req == { 'data[name]': 'foo', 'data[city]': 'bar' }
```

Hope that gives you more ideas, you can call a JS function and do all this mutation if needed.